# bat script to check event viewer for error then run another bat to fix that error

Tags: cmd, event-viewer

> I was wondering if one could use a bat script to check event viewer
>   for certain application errors, and if that error occurs, then it
>   should call another bat file.
>
> for example...
>
> i have a bat file called reset_IE.bat which clears IE temp files, and
>   resets it to factory default, which allready works.
>
> how can i use cmd to check event viewer for a certain error, then run
>   the reset_IE.bat if necessray.
>
> the main bat file will eventually contain many check for various
>   errors, for different software errors.

I found and example, with one of my users just now... where outlook keeps on asking for safemode and then restarts again... you need to delete outcmd.dat file...

How do i check eventviewer using wevutil.exe or any other util... to check application logs for Faulting application outlook.exe, and then call another bat file called something like fix_outlook_safemode.bat

which will in turn run

```
del "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\outcmd.dat"
```

Comment: This sounds more like a job for scripts?

Comment: what os are you running?

Comment: @Kayasax shouldn't matter, but it would be between windows xp and windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with windows2003 (maybe XP) you can use the built-in [eventtriggers.exe utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901.aspx)

example this will execute raiseevent.cmd when a disk is full (eventid 2013 of source srv):

```
eventtriggers /create /TR "disk_full" /TK "C:\WINNT\system32\events\raiseEvent.cmd %computername% system 2013 Srv"  /EID 2013 /SO "Srv"
```

As you can see you can transmit whatever parameters you want to the batch

with win2k8 and 7 you can create a task in the taskscheduler that will be trigger if an event occurs.